# transfer the values from one page to another?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have to pass the values for confirmation from the user from page to another page,
So I have constructed a `registration.php` page(view file) using `jQuery` I am submitting the form using `Ajax` call 
I use this method :

```
   form.submit(function(){
     if(validateFirstName(){
    var str = '';
                str += 'action='+'registration'+'&';
                str += 'f_name='+$("#f_name").val()+'&';
var confirmation_page = confirmation_pg(getUrl+'registration/confirmation.php', str);
return true;
    }else{
     return false
    }
    };
```

to submit this form .From this submission method how can i redirect the page to 
confirmation page and on submitting that page how can i send data to server?

Please help,
thanks

Comment: sorry but i cannot understand the question can you elaborate a bit

Comment: if you are asking about redirecting page then use 
`location.href= 'http://mysite.com/my_page/?a=123'`

Comment: how is this different from your other post?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792613/how-can-i-transfer-values-from-one-page-to-another

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is have your confirmation.php page store the parameters from your submission into hidden fields and post the values when the user has "confirmed" on the confirmation page.   To which then your confirmation.php page can do whatever with the POSTed data.